# How can i get array value when i'm on edit page?

Tags: php, explode, laravel-5.8, implode

I'm storing some array using PHP *implode* method on my project. Now i want to get those value when i want to edit.

Check my create.blade.php page code below:

```
<div class="custom-checkbox">
  <label for="receive[]">Select Receive Funds</label>
    @foreach($funds as $fund)
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="receive[]" id="{{$fund->id}}" value="{{$fund->id}}">
          <label for="{{$fund->id}}"  class="custom-control-label">{{$fund->title}}</label>
       </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

And here is my array store code:

```
$form_data = array('receive'=>implode(',', (array)($request->receive)),)
```

Now, how can i get the array on checkbox as clicked on create.blade.php

Currently i'm using same method for edit. so i don't get any array value on that page.

For Update i use this code:

```
$form_data = array('receive'=>implode(',', (array)($request->receive)),)
```

on edit.blade.php i'm using:

```
<label for="receive[]">Receive Funds:</label>
   @foreach($funds as $fund)
     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
       <input class="custom-control-input" type="checkbox" name="receive[]" id="{{$fund->id}}" value="{{$fund->id}}">
           <label for="{{$fund->id}}"  class="custom-control-label">{{$fund->title}}</label>
     </div>
  @endforeach
```

**How can i get those value?**

Comment: @Don'tPanic no that didn't work..

Comment: It does work, and it is the way to do what you are trying to do :-) If you're having trouble, edit your question and explain what you've tried, and what happened.